# data-val value less than $1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." id="Amount" type="text" value class="input-validation-error">
```

I have above HTML generated. It works well except if user is trying to enter less than $1. user types .72 in the text box then it gives an error The field Amount must be a number. if user is typing 0.72 then it works fine.

What could be a fix to this

Comment: Where is your validation script? is this something built into asp.net mvc? If it is, then it probably doesn't have anything to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not say where and how you validate . anyway try this jquery function

.isNumeric()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/